# Python IMAP - decoding text with BASE64 encoding and KOI8-R charset

Tags: python, character-encoding, imap

I have an IMAP email part which looks like this:

```
(b'TEXT', b'HTML', (b'CHARSET', b'KOI8-R'), None, None, b'BASE64', 3304, 42, None, None, None)
```

I am using [IMAPClient](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient) to parse emails, and I am having trouble trying to decode the email body into human readable characters. My code looks like this:

```
bytes = imap_server.fetch(msgid, "BODY['1']")[msgid][b'BODY[1]']
rs = base64.b64decode(bytes)
rs = rs.decode('KOI8-R')
```

As a result, I get abracadabra like this:

```
ЪьЪЮJFIFHHЪАюExifMM*
```

The value of `bytes` variable is something like:

```
b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QTARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAA...
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

BTW, I have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the source code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably grabbed the wrong section, or the server misparsed the message.    This is likely a JPEG image.  It decodes to:

\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x04\xc0Exif...

JFIF and Exif is indicative of a JPEG image.

Comment: God damn. I have really grabbed wrong part. That's it) Thanks